# How to list all the names of the controls in a command bar in vba

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to list all the control's names pertaining to a command bar and the corresponding index?

I was playing around with this but I have clearly have the wrong syntax.

```
Sub test3()
i = 0
For Each ctl In CommandBars(1).Controls
    i = i + 1
    Debug.Print ctl.Properties.Name & " " & i
Next ctl

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: `Properties` is a collection class. Have you tried `Debug.Print ctl.Name`?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes I have. I get a Object doesn't support this property or method error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are arranged in two levels. Try this:

```
Sub test3()
    i = 0
    For Each ctl In CommandBars(1).Controls
        For Each ctl2 In ctl.Controls
            i = i + 1
            Debug.Print ctl2.Caption & " " & i
        Next ctl2
    Next ctl

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. Am I right in thinking if I want to execute such a control through vba I can use the index that is produced from your code. Ie `Application.CommandBars(1).Controls(167).Execute`

Comment: @SadMrFrown CommandBarControl items have an `ID` that you should probably be using for that purpose, rather than `i` which is just a loop counter your user code.

Comment: It's dangerous. That number isn't predictable and you might execute something completely different. Dangerous, but possible. Don't do it.

Comment: @Sam Noted! Without going too far off topic, I was hoping this process would provide the index of a .com addin that i could then execute. I can see what I would believe the addin's index would be but I don't know how I would execute it. What is the best property to call the control to execute...